# Redis Sentinel is not promoting a replica to be the new master. Down server master is still seen as a master

Tags: redis, failover, redis-sentinel

I'm trying to set up the Redis sentinel configuration in Ubuntu. When I tried to failover scenario I couldn't be successful.

I created  1 master (A) and 2 replica nodes (B, C). Then I made configuration for Sentinels.
To test the failover I have stopped the Redis services on the master server. Then connected to a Redis replica server. I have checked to log in to see one of the replica nodes become a new master.
But I saw that the new master node is still A.
I don't know what I'm missing. Do you have any idea?

I followed this sample:
https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-high-availability-redis-using-sentinel-in-ubuntu/

Some part of the log: (I wrote A for ip of master node)
`# +elected-leader master mymaster A 6379` # +failover-state-select-slave master mymaster A 6379
`# -failover-abort-no-good-slave master mymaster A 6379`

Comment: Connect to your master and see if the slaves are connected to the master or not by running INFO REPPLICATION command on master

Comment: @AnkitSahay To check failover I closed Redis server in the master node, so I could not run ınfo replication command on the master. But when I run this command on one of the slaves I see master_host:A